# Can I write events to Google Calendar from my android application?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

Can I write from my application events to Google calendar, where I will set description of my event, and set email reminder, for get mail with my task in some time?

I don't need to open calendar "edit screen", I want to set all data from my Activity, and synchronize with Google Calendar account on background.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

There are web [APIs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) by Google to modify Google calendar. So, you can fire an http request from your android client to do whatever you want to do with calendar.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okey. I`m try to make all step by step, but it really need to add my test application to google developers console (Step 2: Enable the Calendar API)? It  need add my credit card, i dont have it. Its normal or it exsist some another method to do this? Does work my test project without this step? Thanks.

Comment: No. You don't need to add your credit card if you have less number of requests per day. And they provide free 1,000,000 requests/day. Does your application need more than that?

Comment: Now, i do test application for see how it work, becouse later I need to integrate this to my app in production. I think, when I do it, the credit card will need?

Comment: I don't think you need to add credit card unless you want more quota. So, by default, the calendar API won't give any result if it exceeds the quota. So, as far as that is okay, no need to add any credit card details!

Comment: I have never heard of the calendar api costing anything.   Even if you extend your quota.  you don't need a credit card

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can you will need to use the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)  Google has a number of tutorials [android](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android)

A simple java example found on page [events.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

```
// Initialize Calendar service with valid OAuth credentials
Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials)
    .setApplicationName("applicationName").build();

// Create and initialize a new event
Event event = new Event();
event.setSummary("Appointment");
event.setLocation("Somewhere");

ArrayList<EventAttendee> attendees = new ArrayList<EventAttendee>();
attendees.add(new EventAttendee().setEmail("attendeeEmail"));
// ...
event.setAttendees(attendees);

Date startDate = new Date();
Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 3600000);
DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));

// Insert the new event
Event createdEvent = service.events().insert('primary', event).execute();
```

**Tip:**  use calendar.list to find the calendar Id.